# Title the Result from SphinxSearch

Tags: sphinx

Any way I can title the search results?

Example:
`select name from person ;`
Will give

abhilash joseph c

But i want it to be 'Abhilash Joseph C'

Can I write udf for sphinx? How can I do it ?

Comment: 'title the result' - what does that mean? Do you mean change to 'Title Case'? While it probably could be done with a Sphinx UDF, would probably be easier just to do it in the Application. Would have to write it as C code for a UDF. If you not an experienced C-coder, going to be tricky.

Comment: Yes . To change to title case